# Supress correction by argument in zsh

Tags: linux, zsh, zsh-completion

Suppose I have the file tree

```
-A_dir/
  - a_test_file1
```

Doing `mv a_test_file1 a_test_file2` results in an annoying correction query. The second argument of `mv` should never be corrected, as it may or may not point to an existing node on the filesystem. However, the first argument may be corrected because it must always be a valid node.

This is an common use case, where I'd only like `zsh` to correct certain arguments in a command. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `However, the first argument may be corrected because it must always be a valid node.` -> How do you want it corrected? By searching subdirectories? How about when more than one directory contain same file?

Comment: I think the OP is happy with the default corrections applied to the first argument, as long as *no* corrections are applied to the second argument to `mv`.

Comment: @konsolebox, chepner is correct.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you need a *correction* i.e. replace the first argument with another? If that's the case if you have `a/a.txt` and you have `b/a.txt`, and your current command is `mv a.txt a2.txt` (which would cause file does not exist error), would you replace `a.txt` with `a/a.txt` or `b/a.txt`? Or do you just need to check if the file exists and do nothing if it doesn't?

Comment: More simply put, the if the second argument to mv is not a valid filesystem node, zsh will try to correct it to one. This is not correct behavior because I could be moving it to a new file (i.e. one that does not yet exist). The first argument should still be corrected because it does need to be a valid filesystem node.

Answer (score 0):

Placing this as an answer because it is too much text for a comment... but this is really a comment.

Honestly, a cursory reading of the manual indicates that this is not possible without deep hackery. `correct` corrects commands and `correct_all` tries to correct all arguments.

I thought about doing something like

```
function mv {
  emulate -L zsh
  CORRECT_IGNORE='*'$@[-1]'*'
  command mv $@
}
```

But it does not work as `CORRECT_IGNORE` does not apply to the correction of filenames. If you could find out how to produce corrections from a list of arguments, you could generate corrections for all arguments that you want corrected and later call `nocorrect mv ...`.